# Ошибки в отображении swiper при display; block после клика

Tags: javascript, wordpress, swiper

Я сделал один слайдер для разных товаров - Новые, Популярные, Рекомендуемые скопировав из офф демо https://codesandbox.io/s/nygnt , они просто выводят разный товар по параметрам с вукомерса. Когда первый раз загружается слайдер то все нормально, в дальнейшем же, при добавлении к блоку свойства display: block при клику на Новы, Популярные, Рекомендуемые появляется один большой слайд. Что это за дичь? лечится только если самому изменять масштаб браузера растягивая, сужая его.

Может быть это проблема xampp а не свайпера? Т.к до этого работало все нормально, а затем стали появляться такие проблемы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй добавить 2 новых строчки - `observer: true` и `observeParents: true`  в инициализацию свайпера
`new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {observer: true, observeParents: true, ... })`

Или после добавления `display:block` вызови `swiper.update();`